# Cluster assignment in ST_ClusterKMeans

Tags: postgis, clustering

If I have 100 rows of polygons, and I choose number of clusters to be 10, is it always the case that each of the 100 polygons would be assigned to a cluster? So there will never be a "leftover" polygon with lets say "Null" cluster id?

Comment: That is my understanding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you would never get a null cluster id, regardless of the number of clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested st_clusterkmeans using 22 random records from a table and 10 clusters.   I expect all 22 records to be given a cluster id, and all records do have a cluster id.  However, you can see there is an uneven distribution of records per cluster id. There are 6 clusters with only 1 record (0,2,4,5,6,8), and 1 cluster with 7 records (3).

```
select st_clusterkmeans(geom, 10) over() cid, ogc_fid from (select * from pgc_md_all_roads limit 22) f
```

This is the result I get:

| cid | ogc_fid |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 30126 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 53 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 3 | 13 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 10 |
| 7 | 12 |
| 7 | 19 |
| 8 | 14 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 9 | 11 |
| 9 | 15 |
| 9 | 17 |